# Not using any kind of javafx application still it says extend javafx

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using jdk 1.8 , jre 1.8 and eclipse juno.Whenever i use to run my program with eclipse it gives me this error

```
Error: Main method not found in class A, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

my basic  program is

```
public class A {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
}
```

Then i tried to run my program from CMD on the first time it run successfully after that it also start giving me this error..Points to remember

1. When i create a new project i use  default jre.which is jre 8.
2. I am not using any kind of javaFx Application.My basic program is in front of you all
3. I cant every time extend javafx .So i need a strong way to resolve it.
4. I run a program from the command prompt for the first time it run ,but when i run another program with little bit of change it did not run.

I am stuck here guys please give me a solution for that and  a little bit of explanation for that will be appreciated..

Comment: The code you showed us, is it the one that's running or giving an error?

Comment: "*for the first time it run ,but when i run another program with little bit of change it did not run.*"  What if you remove this change, would it run again?

Comment: System.out.println("Yes");..This change i have created .And no it did not run

Comment: what is the command you executed from command line?

Comment: Can you possibly have multiple `A.class` files in your `classpath`?

Comment: javac A.java and to run that java A

Comment: NO i don't have multiple classes

Answer (score 0):

Please, close your cmd prompt.

And reopen cmd prompt.

Then open your directory containing pom.xml

To build your project, Type : `mvn install`

Then run the java code. For eg,

```
java -cp target/sample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.maven.sample.HelloMaven
```

Here `HelloMaven` is the class name.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Imported java.lang.String and the error went off.

```
import java.lang.String;
```